# Proguard rules for Maps v3.0.0 Beta

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been trying to implement the new maps api that google encourages people to start using and I can't get over an error I've been getting (works fine with maps v2).

I tried the proguard rules from google maps sample codes but they only kept the v2 rules there somehow. Are they supposed to work even for the v3?

The map class is quite basic:

```java
package com.example.test2.Fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.test2.R;
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    private final int zoomValue = 13;

    public MainMapFragment() {
    }

    public static MainMapFragment newInstance() {
        return new MainMapFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_map, container, false);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onStart();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

My Proguard rules file:

```
# Jackson
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties class * { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxsml.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility { 
    public static final com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}

## General
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature,Exceptions,InnerClasses

-optimizations !code/simplification/variable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

# The Maps API uses custom Parcelables.
# Use this rule (which is slightly broader than the standard recommended one)
# to avoid obfuscating them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}

# The Maps API uses serialization.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

And the error I'm getting when trying to open the map on my phone (Xiaomi Redmi 4):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test2, PID: 26504
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.ex.zzd.<clinit>(GmmSettings.java:111)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.dk.zza.zzA(DaggerMapCoreEnvironmentComponent.java:983)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.gu.zzat.zza(RendererFactoryImpl.java:63)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzav.zza(GoogleMapImpl.java:59)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzcp.zza(MapViewDelegateImpl.java:3)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.it.zzcq.zza(MapViewDelegateImpl.java:11)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(MapView.java:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zab.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zaa.onDelegateCreated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(MapView.java:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:22)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:26)
        at d.b.a.f.t.onCreateView(MainMapFragment.java:58)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595)
        at b.j.a.i.a(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at b.j.a.i.p(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at b.j.a.i.a(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at b.j.a.a.g(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at b.j.a.i.b(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
        at b.j.a.i.a(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at b.j.a.i.c(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
        at b.j.a.i.y(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at b.j.a.i$b.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.ex.zzi.<init>(GmmSettings.java:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.ex.zzh.<init>(GmmSettings.java:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.maps.ex.zzi.<clinit>(GmmSettings.java:16)
```

When I turn off minifyEnabled and shrinkResources it works just fine.

Has anyone stumbled upon this? I tried googling this error but didn't find anything anywhere.

Any response appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Answer accurate as of 2020/01/21; verify fix is still necessary in the [latest SDK version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration) before applying.*

---

I encountered this same issue with the currently published 3.0.0-beta AAR. I reported the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148084488). The workaround I suggest is to add the following to your app's ProGuard configuration:

```
# Fix maps 3.0.0-beta crash:
-keep,allowoptimization class com.google.android.libraries.maps.** { *; }

# Fix maps 3.0.0-beta marker taps ignored:
-keep,allowoptimization class com.google.android.apps.gmm.renderer.** { *; }
```

Hopefully the Google team will add these (or more refined) rules to the ProGuard configuration embedded in the 3.0.0-beta AAR, at which point these additional rules should become unnecessary. Unfortunately, since the 3.0.0-beta SDK is not visibly versioned, knowing when that happens might only be possible by starring and following the issue linked at the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Write this Rules  in you Proguard file

```
-keepattributes Signature,InnerClasses
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes *Annotation* 
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

And also Ensure that Your all Model classes has @Keep annotation

Comment: All Models do have @Keep but I don't see why would google maps have to do anything with my models. Also I already have these proguard rules there but  thank you anyways.